# 404 on Glassfish rest application

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I have a REST application that I swear worked yesterday. Today all paths, including the rest root, give a 404

Our REST root is defined here:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application
{
}
```

And my individual process is this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/profileService")
public class ProfileSettingsComposite extends BaseComposite {
...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/ContactPreferences")
@LoggerConfig(logType = "ERROR")
@Interceptors(value = { ExceptionHandler.class, MetricLogger.class, MethodLogger.class, MethodCacher.class })
public GetContactTypeComposite getContactPreferences(...
```

So I should be able to hit my webservice at

```
localhost:8080/ma-ejb/rest/profileService/ContactPreferences?blahparamblah
```

I have confirmed that the application is deployed to glassfish in the admin console. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: What has changed since yesterday? Also you are expecting parameter ? Do you see any errors when your app comes up?

Comment: Just the 404. Params are expected, and I include them when I run it locally. I just didn't want to show a page and a half worth of JSON in the question.

That said, right after I asked this question I noticed that something in my latest pull from the repo mucked up all of my maven settings. I don't know if that's necessarily causing the problem, but it's silly to try to diagnose without eliminating those first.